# How to solve $z$ from a matrix equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For two vectors $z\in R^d$ and a scalar $y_i \in R$, and a symmetric matrix $A, B, C\in R^{d\times d}$, if we have
$$\sum_{i=1}^n[y_iAB-zC]=0$$

But how to write an expression to represent $z$ in terms of $x_i$ and $y_i$? Something like
$$z=?....$$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let $z=(z^1, \dots, z^d)$, $x_i=(x_i^1,\dots,x_i^d)$ and $s=\sum y_i$. Then
$$\frac{\sum x_iy_i}{\sum y_i}=\frac{y_1}{s}x_1 + \dots + \frac{y_n}{s}x_n = 
\left( \frac{y_1}{s}x_1^1,\dots,\frac{y_1}{s}x_1^d\right) + \cdots +
\left( \frac{y_n}{s}x_n^1,\dots,\frac{y_n}{s}x_n^d\right),$$ so
$$ z^j = \frac{y_1}{s}x_1^j + \dots + \frac{y_n}{s}x_n^j = \sum_i \frac{y_i}{s}x_i^j=\frac{1}{s}\sum_i y_ix_i^j$$
where $1\leq j\leq d$.

Comment: Is this same as $z=\frac{\sum_i y_i x_i}{\sum_i y_i}$?

Comment: Yes, it is. You're right. I was thinking you need $z^j$.

Comment: Wait, But it seems that we cannot say $z=\frac{\sum y_ix_i}{\sum y_i}$ from $z^j$. Because that is $x_i^j$ in the numerator but not $x_i$.

Comment: Lets try an example: $n=2, d=3$ Then $z=\frac{\sum y_ix_i}{\sum y_i}=\frac{1}{y_1+y_2} \cdot (y_1x_1+y_2x_2)=\frac{1}{y_1+y_2} \cdot ((y_1x_1^1,y_1x_1^2,y_1x_1^3) + (y_2x_2^1,y_2x_2^2,y_2x_2^3)) = \frac{1}{y_1+y_2} \cdot (y_1x_1^1+y_2x_2^1, y_1x_1^2+y_2x_2^2,y_1x_1^3+y_2x_2^3)$, so now $z=(z^1,z^2,z^3)=\frac{1}{y_1+y_2} \cdot (y_1x_1^1+y_2x_2^1, y_1x_1^2+y_2x_2^2,y_1x_1^3+y_2x_2^3)$. For example $z^2=\frac{1}{y_1+y_2}\cdot (y_1x_1^2+y_2x_2^2)$, what is exactly what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: In your original post (still anyone can check editing history) you wrote $zI=\frac{\sum x_iy_i}{\sum y_i}I$, and for this z I wrote answer. Why you edited the post?